# Weird complex number inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let z1,z2 be complex numbers with $|z_1|=|z_2|=1$. Prove that $|z_1+1|+|z_2+1|+|z_1z_2+1| \ge 2$.

My attempt: I started with $z_1=e^{i\theta_1}$ and $z_2=e^{i\theta_2}$ and then plugged them into the equations given but as it came to $\theta_1+\theta_2$ in the last modulus I got pretty confused regarding how to proceed.

Please help me out.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1975274/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7Cz_1%2B1%7C%2B%7Cz_2%2B1%7C%2B%7Cz_1z_2%2B1%7C%20%5Cge%202%24&p=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $1=|\bar z_2| $, mutliplying with it we get $|z_1z_2+1|=|z_1+\bar z_2|=|-z_1-\bar z_2|$, while $|z_2+1|=|\bar z_2+1|$, so now the triangle inequality:

$|z_1+1|+|\bar z_2+1|+|-z_1-\bar z_2| \ge |1+1|=2$ does it!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: happy to be of help