# Prove $\left|1+z_1\right| +\left|1+z_2 \right| + \left|1+z_1z_2\right|\geq 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am struggling with this problem

> Let $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$ prove that $$\left|1+z_1\right| +\left|1+z_2 \right| + \left|1+z_1z_2\right|\geq 2$$

I know a similar question has been solved: [if $|z_i|=1$ prove $|z_1+1|+|z_2+1|+|z_1z_2+1|\ge 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1975274/if-z-i-1-prove-z-11z-21z-1z-21-ge-2) .
However, I don't have the $|z_1|=|z_2|=1$ condition, so I am not sure if the question is wrong or the last condition is implicit. This is the work I have done:

\begin{align*}
            |1+z_1|+|1+z_2|+|1+z_1 z_2| &= |1+z_1| + |1+z_2|+|-(1+z_1z_2)|\\
                                &\geq |1+z_1| + \left|(1+z_2)-(1+z_1z_2)\right|\\
                                &= |1+z_1|+ |z_2-z_1z_2|\\
                                &\geq |(1+z_1)+(z_2-z_1z_2)|
  \end{align*}

I'll appreciate your help. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Are you sure there’s no bounds on the modulus of your $z_j$’s? $j=1,2,3$

Comment: Yes, it's all information I got.

Comment: Someone just answered , pretty clean solution too !

Comment: This question is superior to the linked question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If $|z_2|\geq 1$, then
\begin{align*}
|1+z_1|+|1+z_2|+|1+z_1z_2|
&\geq |1+z_1|+|(1+z_2)-(1+z_1z_2)|\\
&=|1+z_1|+|z_2||1-z_1|\\
&\geq |1+z_1|+|1-z_1|\geq 2,
\end{align*}
where the last step uses the triangle inequality. If $|z_2|\leq 1$, then
\begin{align*}
|1+z_1|+|1+z_2|+|1+z_1z_2|
&\geq|z_2||1+z_1|+|1+z_2|+|1+z_1z_2|\\
&\geq|(1+z_2)-(z_2+z_1z_2)|+|1+z_1z_2|\\
&=|1-z_1z_2|+|1+z_1z_2|\geq 2.
\end{align*}

Comment: So are you fixing $z_1$ and considering cases for the modulus of $z_2$?

Comment: @HossienS'MyMathYourMath' Yes, although I wouldn't necessarily think about it as "fixing $z_1$." If $z_1$ and $z_2$ are given to you, either $|z_2|\geq 1$ and you can follow the first computation, or $|z_2|\leq 1$ and you can follow the second computation.

Comment: Makes sense. As the same would hold if you fixed $z_2$ and put those condition on modulus of $z_1$

Comment: Is there a solution which doesn't split the two cases of $|z_2|$? I had a go but couldn't find one.